# Associating Custom Settings with a Connected App in a 2GP

Tags: managed-package, customsetting, 2gp

In our 1GP, there is a Custom Settings object and a Connected App. On orgs where the 1GP is installed, if you go to **Setup** -> **App Manager**, select the Connected App in the list and pick **Manage**, you see the Custom Settings that were included in the package. This makes it easy to find and edit them. Here's a partial screenshot of the page shown when you Manage the 1GP. Notice the **Custom Settings** section near the bottom.
[image]

We are releasing our first 2GP. It has a folder under force-app/main/default/objects containing the Custom Settings object and associated fields.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customSettingsType>List</customSettingsType>
    <description>Organization settings for Company Connector for Salesforce</description>
    <enableFeeds>false</enableFeeds>
    <label>Company Connector Settings</label>
    <visibility>Public</visibility>
</CustomObject>
```

When the 2GP is installed in an org, the **Custom Settings** are installed and working but they are no longer visible when doing a **Manage** of the Connected App from the **App Manager**.

The Manage page looks the same as the screenshot above except the **Custom Settings** section is missing. I have to go to Setup -> Custom Code -> Custom Settings to access it now.

Has anyone been able to overcome this issue with a 2GP?

Comment: I am confused. You mention connected app but then discuss custom settings? Please [edit] to specifically clarify the problem. Perhaps including info showing the sfdx project structure and relevant metadata files and the way things are shown in the Setup UI would help too... screenshots might work for this...

Comment: Hi Phil W - just added a screenshot and clarifying info. Hope this helps and thanks for looking at this.